# How to receive ACTION_SCREEN_OFF if my app is removed from memory?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I can register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF in code, since it doesn't work in the manifest.

But if android removes my app from memory (no longer wants), I don't receive the code registered broadcasts anymore...

Is there a way to make sure I will always receive it, as is the case with manifest registered intent receivers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Activities are only for UI work, so once your Activity is dismissed(no longer visible and destroyed for w/e reason) all registers receivers are destroyed as well(not supposed to let this happen btw).

If you ALWAYS want to receive the broadcasts you need to implement a service and register your broadcast receiver from that service. Only you can judge if this is warranted or not, generally it is not recommended to have a full service running 24/7, but if its needed its needed.